# GWT: background-image property not shown in injected external css file

Tags: gwt

In my sub-module i would like to inject the css at runtime:

```java
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle
{
    Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create( Resources.class );

    @Source( "pagedown.css" )
    @NotStrict
    CssResource css();
}
```

from java i use `Resources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();` and it works just fine except the image does not show, in pagedown.css:

```css
.wmd-button>span {
    background-image: url(pagedown/wmd-buttons.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
```

The reason is because there is no way to find the image. The above code is in my sub-project(sub-module) for reuse, **i have to copy the image to my app project to have it work**, it is pretty cumbersome and break encapsulation, is there a way to solve this?

EDIT

---

If i modified the above css to `background-image: url(myapp/pagedown/wmd-buttons.png)`; it will just work, however, because this css is in sub-project and never know the name of my app project, so if i hard code it like this, one day i have another project use this component, i have to modify it to `myOtherApp/pagedown/wmd-buttons.png`, you can see the two projects conflict and can not use my component at the same time.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know this method of injecting style on run-time, but in GWT i do this by directly setting the style property for the component from the java class itself.

Like this sample code: 
Widget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("style attribute in camel-case format","style value");

isn't that usable in your situation?

Comment: if you want detailed sample code please let me know.

Comment: At the time of making your war file, please ensure that all your images from sub project comes under war/images directory...

Comment: @PrateekSharma, that's the Key, so i have to copy the image to my app project every time i use this component, because it is in my sub project, how to avoid this copy everytime?

Comment: You don't need to copy, modify script which will do this for you.For  instance, if you make your war file through script then addthis also in your script. Because ultimately there should be one coherent structure

Comment: Well, copy by script is also a kind of copy i think, i'd like to see a clean way to do this: the app project will just use the component and never consider other stuff such as copy resources of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a workaround: let the component accept a parameter in constructor, the parameter is the project base url, which used to get the corrent image url, in the constructor, i attach the correct image-background url using GWTQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for this style atribute is: `background-image: url("pagedown/wmd-buttons.png");` 
So the code becomes

```
wmd-button>span {
    background-image: url("pagedown/wmd-buttons.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
```

not this:

```
.wmd-button>span {
    background-image: url(pagedown/wmd-buttons.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
```

Comment: ensure 'pagedown' folder is in war folder of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the problem is not `url(pagedown/wmd-buttons.png)`, what i concern is, how to use image in sub-module, to make it reusable, please see my question for details.

Comment: use database to store image and retrieve it on your need. Is n't that possible?

That means always retrieve images from a url, which in-turn is a result of query to a image database, which shared among different projects. :)

Comment: Yes that's possible, but not quite suitable for my current project. thanks again.